# jquery, form not validating

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Im relatively new to jQuery and am having to use it as part of a project for uni. The problem im having is that it seems to not be calling the jQuery file properly or something as any inputs will be accepted and it isnt flagging required fields. I have some success doing inline type statements but for the sake of tidyness i would like to have all the rules in one place. Ive been stuck for the last few hours looking for a missing { or , and reading other posts but no luck yet.

Here is my code anyway (still in its draft stages), thanks in advance for any help

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
$( "#registerForm" ).validate({
        rules: {    
            email:{
                required:true,
                email:true
            },
            emailRepeat:{
                required:true,
                email:true
                equalTo: "#email"
            },
            password:{
                required:true
            },
            passwordRepeat:{
                required:true
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            fullname:{
                required:true,
                minlength:2,
                maxlength:15
            },
            phone :{
                number:true,
                digits:true,
                minlength:7,
                maxlength:10
            },
            street:{

            },
            city:{
                required:true
            },
            country:{
                required:true
            }
        },
        messages:{
                }

    });
});
</script>

<title>Register</title>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="masthead"> </div>
<div id="top-nav">
    <ul id="top">
        <li> 
            <a href="books.htm">Browse Books</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="about.htm">About Us </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="signup.htm">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="login.htm">Log In</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="profile.htm">Your Account</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>

<div id="main-content">
    <form id ="registerForm" action="" class="register">
            <h1>Registration</h1>

            <div class="infobox">
                    <p>Please enter all the required fields and submit once completed</p>
                </div>
            <fieldset class="row1">
                <legend>Account Details
                </legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Email *
                    </label>
                    <input name="email" id="email" />
                    <label>Repeat email *
                    </label>
                    <input name="emailRepeat" id="emailRepeat" type="text"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password*
                    </label>
                    <input name="password" id="password" type="password"/>
                    <label>Repeat Password*
                    </label>
                    <input name="passwordRepeat" id="passswordRepeat" type="password"/>
                    <label class="obinfo">* required fields
                    </label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Personal Details
                </legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Name *
                    </label>
                    <input name="fullname" id="fullname"type="text" class="long" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="optional">Phone 
                    </label>
                    <input name="phone" id="phone" type="text"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="optional">Street
                    </label>
                    <input name="street" id="street" type="text" class="long"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>City *
                    </label>
                    <input name="city" id="city" type="text" class="long" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Country *
                    </label>
                    <select>
                        <option>
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">New Zealand 
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">Australia
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">United States
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">Canada
                        </option>

                    </select>
                </p>
                            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="row3">
                <legend>Further Information
                </legend>
                <p>
                    <label>Gender *</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="radio"/>
                    <label class="gender">Male</label>
                    <input type="radio" value="radio"/>
                    <label class="gender">Female</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Birthdate *
                    </label>
                    <select name="day" id="day"class="date">
                        <option value="">
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">01
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">02
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">03
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">04
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">05
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">06
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">07
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">08
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">09
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">10
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">11
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">12
                        </option>
                        <option value="13">13
                        </option>
                        <option value="14">14
                        </option>
                        <option value="15">15
                        </option>
                        <option value="16">16
                        </option>
                        <option value="17">17
                        </option>
                        <option value="18">18
                        </option>
                        <option value="19">19
                        </option>
                        <option value="20">20
                        </option>
                        <option value="21">21
                        </option>
                        <option value="22">22
                        </option>
                        <option value="23">23
                        </option>
                        <option value="24">24
                        </option>
                        <option value="25">25
                        </option>
                        <option value="26">26
                        </option>
                        <option value="27">27
                        </option>
                        <option value="28">28
                        </option>
                        <option value="29">29
                        </option>
                        <option value="30">30
                        </option>
                        <option value="31">31
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="month" id="month">
                        <option value="">                    
                        </option>
                        <option value="1">January
                        </option>
                        <option value="2">February
                        </option>
                        <option value="3">March
                        </option>
                        <option value="4">April
                        </option>
                        <option value="5">May
                        </option>
                        <option value="6">June
                        </option>
                        <option value="7">July
                        </option>
                        <option value="8">August
                        </option>
                        <option value="9">September
                        </option>
                        <option value="10">October
                        </option>
                        <option value="11">November
                        </option>
                        <option value="12">December
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <input name="year" id="year" class="year" type="text" size="4" maxlength="4"/>e.g 1976
                </p>
                                                   </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="row4">
                <legend>Terms and Mailing
                </legend>
                <p class="agreement">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                    <label>*  I accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a></label>
                </p>
                <p class="agreement">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                    <label>I want to receive personalized offers by your site</label>
                </p>
                <p class="agreement">
                    <input type="checkbox" value=""/>
                    <label>Allow partners to send me personalized offers and related services</label>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div>
        </form> 
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>
       <a href="#top"> Back to Top </a>  </p>
    <p>
        Your E-Book Company Ltd 2015  </p>
</div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in the dev console?

Comment: Dont you think `email:true` should have comma.

Comment: You should be paying attention to your console errors and have all syntax errors fixed before posting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing commas at the end of your rule properties here:

```
        emailRepeat:{
            required:true,
            email:true,
            equalTo: "#email"
        },
        ...
        passwordRepeat:{
            required:true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
```

Each line except the last line should end in a comma otherwise you will get a syntax error

Comment: Thanks alot, feel like a bit of an idiot wasting peoples time for something that simple. Swear i looked at those commas a few times, must be getting old haha

Comment: @RyanMillar , hope you wont do such silly mistake again as you will have pretty complex tasks in future in your project. And if you go like that you will be posting 1000 such questions ! Anyways , better luck. :)

Comment: @RyanMillar no problem its very easy to overlook the obvious when debugging especially when learning something new. Don't forget to click the checkmark icon to vote the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You must define the keys of rule object in string 
Like this

```
$( "#registerForm" ).validate({
    rules: {    
        "email":{
            required:true,
            email:true
        },
        "emailRepeat":{
            required:true,
            email:true,
            equalTo: "#email"
        },
        "password":{
            required:true
        },
        "passwordRepeat":{
            required:true,
            equalTo: "#password"
        },
        "fullname":{
            required:true,
            minlength:2,
            maxlength:15
        },
        "phone" :{
            number:true,
            digits:true,
            minlength:7,
            maxlength:10
        },
        "street":{

        },
        "city":{
            required:true
        },
        "country":{
            required:true
        }
    },
    messages:{
            }

});
```